# Jquery autocomplete minlength 1 first use

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/8xPmB/

Can somesone find out why it does'nt work at first time:

When typing a letter in the text field, nothing happen.
Then, when clearing the field and type again a letter, it work well.

Thank you.

code:

```
function search(){
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",    
     ];

     $( "#product" ).autocomplete({
                        source: availableTags,                        
                        minLength: 1,
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simpler test:

HTML

```
< input id="product" type="text" />
```

js

```
var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",    
     ];

     $( "#product" ).autocomplete({
                        source: availableTags,                        
                        minLength: 1,
     });
```

I cannot understand why you are trying to encapsulate into a function and why you are turning autocomplete off. This is what affects the normal jQuery behaviour.

Comment: Nice to know I was also able to help you out.